# How to insert R text variables into Latex expressions keeping normal formatting

Tags: r, latex, r-markdown

I want to create Section headers with a for loop and have managed to do this however the text is stuck in math mode formatting. I've tried using Latex syntax to undo this however it did not work as expected:

Code:

````
---
title: "Troubleshooting"
author: "Me"
output: pdf_document
header-includes:
  - \usepackage{amsmath}
---


```{r} 
words <- c("plz_work","better_yet","what_is_this")
```

```{r, results='asis', echo=FALSE}
for (i in 1:3) {
cat('\\subsection{$',words[i],'$}')
}
```
````

Output:

[image: math_converted_text]

If I use the latex notation to convert it to text formatting nothing changes:

````
```{r, results='asis', echo=FALSE}
for (i in 1:3) {
cat('\\subsection{$\text{',words[i],'}$}')
}
```
````

If I escape the `"$\text{..}$"` again i.e. `"$\\text{..}$"` then I get an error:

```
! Missing $ inserted.
<inserted text> 
                $
l.283 \subsection{$\text{ plz_work }$}

Error: Failed to compile test_delete_is_ok.tex. See test_delete_is_ok.log for more info.
Execution halted
```

Adding more escapes doesnt help. If I try to insert this variable without math mode I also get the same error that I just listed:

````
```{r, results='asis', echo=FALSE}
for (i in 1:3) {
cat('\\subsection{',words[i],'}')
}
```

! Missing $ inserted.
<inserted text> 
                $
l.283 \subsection{ plz_work }

Error: Failed to compile test_delete_is_ok.tex. See test_delete_is_ok.log for more info.
Execution halted
````

Comment: You cannot use `_` in normal text, it has special meaning for tex, therefore you need to escape it with `\_`

Comment: Thank you - after replacing every instance of `"_"` with `"\\_"` this ran fine and I did not need to use math mode.

Comment: Would you like to write an answer to your question?

Comment: I was unsure whether or not you wanted to write the answer but I've now gone ahead and written one. Thanks again!

Comment: Great answer! Thanks! I'm not familiar with r markdown, so I would not have been able to explain how to actually adapt the tex syntax to work there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned by Samcarter, when using tex you need to also be aware of any tex-related special meanings.

In this instance - the `"_"` symbol is used in tex math mode for signalling a subscript is about to follow. When passing my R strings that contained `"_"` into the tex expression it would throw an error as the `"_"` is reserved for math mode (unless escaped) - this is why I got no error when I enclosed it with `$...$`

The solution for me was to add in escapes before every tex special character:

```
#original
words <- c("plz_work","better_yet","what_is_this")

#modified version. Replace collapse with other tex functions if needed
words2 <- lapply(strsplit(words,"_"), paste, collapse = '\\_')
```

```
for (i in 1:3) {
cat('\\subsection{',words2[[i]],'}')
}
```

[image]

The underscores here are a little long for my liking but you can easily replace the 'collapse' argument to something else which you prefer eg. `... collapse ='\\textunderscore ') ...` also works